# buy one get one choose by customer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to create a custom module for the following requirement

Purchase any product and get free products

Free products for a particular product will be assigned from admin side like related products.

Whenever customer going to buy this product, they shall be able to select the free products from the listing. System should allow the customer select the attributes like color and size of the Product.

Free product is a simple product which can be buy along with other products with normal price.

Whenever increase the product cart quantity, customer can add one more free products attached with the product

Thanks in advance